# HDFS write from kafka : createBlockOutputStream Exception

Tags: docker, hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs

I'm using Hadoop from docker swarm with 1 namenode and 3 datanodes (on 3 physical machines).
i'm also using kafka and kafka connect + hdfs connector to write messages into HDFS in parquet format.

I'm able to write data to HDFS using HDFS clients (hdfs put). 
But when kafka is writing messages, it works at the very beginning, then if fails with this error :

```
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.0.0.8:50010]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
[2018-05-23 10:30:10,125] INFO Abandoning BP-468254989-172.17.0.2-1527063205150:blk_1073741825_1001 (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient:1265)
[2018-05-23 10:30:10,148] INFO Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.0.0.8:50010,DS-cd1c0b17-bebb-4379-a5e8-5de7ff7a7064,DISK] (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient:1269)
[2018-05-23 10:31:10,203] INFO Exception in createBlockOutputStream (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient:1368)
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.0.0.9:50010]
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:534)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1309)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1262)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
```

And then the datanodes are not reachable anymore for the process :

```
[2018-05-23 10:32:10,316] WARN DataStreamer Exception (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient:557)
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /topics/+tmp/test_hdfs/year=2018/month=05/day=23/hour=08/60e75c4c-9129-454f-aa87-6c3461b54445_tmp.parquet could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1733)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2496)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:828)
```

But if I look into the hadoop web admin console, all the nodes seem to be up and OK.

I've checked the hdfs-site and the "dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname" setting is set to true both on namenode and datanodes. All ips in hadoop configuration files are defined using 0.0.0.0 addresses.

I've tried to format the namenode too, but the error happened again.

Could the problem be that Kafka is writing too fast in HDFS, so it overwhelms it? It would be weird as I've tried the same configuration on a smaller cluster and it worked good even with a big throughputof kafka messages.

Do you have any other idea of the origin of this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname=true` has to be configured also to the client side and, following your log stack:

> java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.0.0.9:50010]

I guess `10.0.0.9` refers to a private net IP; thus, it seems that the property is not set in your client within **hdfs-client.xml**.

You can find more detail [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsMultihoming.html#Clients_use_Hostnames_when_connecting_to_DataNodes).